# I can't seem to get my selectList to set its bound variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist

I apologize if this question is quite similar to the others involving selectList.  I have read over them but can't seem to find the solution to my issue.  So I figured after a few days of plugging away I'd give it to the community.

In a nutshell, I have a Visualforce page with a selectList that is populated with the names of Products in Salesforce (there are only two Products).

```
<apex:page controller="EstimatorController" sidebar="false" >
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <h1>Weiss Cosmetic Surgical Estimator</h1>
    <apex:form >
        <p>Patient Name</p>
        <!-- <apex:inputField value="{!PatientName.name}"/> -->
        <br />
        <p>Procedure 1</p>
        <apex:selectList size="1" id="proc1" value="{!productId}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!products}" />
             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" id="changeAction" reRender="calcRegion" status="calcStatus" action="{!findProduct}" />
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:outputPanel >
            <apex:actionRegion id="calcRegion" rendered="true">
            <!-- Click pops up window with the value of my productId var --> 
            <a href="#" onclick="alert ('{!productId}');">Test</a>
            <!-- Test output -->
                <p>Your information is: {!currentPrice}</p>
            <!-- end Test output -->
            </apex:actionRegion>
        </apex:outputPanel>             
        <apex:actionStatus id="calcStatus" startText="Starting..." stopText="Done" for="calcRegion" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

The custom controller for the page follows:

```
public with sharing class EstimatorController {

    /*-------------Variables----------------------*/
    @TestVisible public String productId {get; set;}
    @TestVisible public Product2 mySelectedProduct {get; set;}
    public Decimal currentPrice {get; set;}


    //Retrieve a list of Products we have created in Salesforce
    public List<SelectOption> getProducts () {
            List<Product2> myProducts = [SELECT Name, Id, (Select UnitPrice From PricebookEntries) from Product2];
            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add (new SelectOption ('', 'Select your option'));
            for (Product2 p : myProducts) {
                options.add(new SelectOption (p.Id, p.Name));
            }
            return options;
    }

    //Displays selected product price in field on page
    public PageReference findProduct() {
        //productPrice = productMap.get(productId);
        mySelectedProduct = [Select Id, Name, CreatedDate, (Select UnitPrice from PricebookEntries) from Product2 WHERE Id = :ProductId];
        currentPrice = mySelectedProduct.PriceBookEntries[0].UnitPrice;
       return null;
    } 
}
```

What **should** happen is that next to "Your information is", I should see the corresponding price of the Product.

From the troubleshooting I've been able to do, it seems as if the *productId* variable is not being set, and thus I am not able to get a value for *mySelectedProduct* or a value for *currentPrice*.

I cannot figure out why the *productId* variable isn't being set! :(  I even added a Javscript alert window to show me the value of *productId* after I select an option and it displays nothing.  I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong!

(I'd also truly enjoy constructive criticism if my code is poorly written or any other suggestions you have.  I appreciate it!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing that actionRegion and replacing it with an outputPanel. Using an actionRegion only processes what is inside of it (so the productId is not actually being persisted back to the server since it is set outside of that actionRegion).

```
<apex:outputPanel id="calcRegion">
    <!-- Click pops up window with the value of my productId var --> 
    <a href="#" onclick="alert ('{!productId}');">Test</a>
    <!-- Test output -->
        <p>Your information is: {!currentPrice}</p>
    <!-- end Test output -->
</apex:outputPanel>    
<apex:actionStatus id="calcStatus" startText="Starting..." stopText="Done" />
```

You also don't need to explicitly set the rendered attribute to true. Typically you only use that if you have a variable or logic that determines whether or not to show something.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to use the following, it should work. Instead of rendering the actionRegion inside the outputPanel, try to render the outputPanel itself as:

```
<apex:selectList size="1" id="proc1" value="{!productId}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!products}" />
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" id="changeAction"
        reRender="panelId" status="calcStatus" action="{!findProduct}" />
</apex:selectList>
<apex:outputPanel id="panelId">
    <apex:actionRegion id="calcRegion" rendered="true">
        <!-- Click pops up window with the value of my productId var -->
        <a href="#" onclick="alert ('{!productId}');">Test</a>
        <!-- Test output -->
        <p>Your information is: {!currentPrice}</p>
        <!-- end Test output -->
    </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:outputPanel>
```